# Pure CSS Hamburger menu shows up when resizing viewport before disappearing

Tags: html, css

I have a pure css hamburger menu based on this [codepen](https://codepen.io/zaid03/pen/EBoBoK) and I made my hamburger menu only show up on devices with `768px` width and below, the hamburger menu also has some transitions when opening and closing to make it look smooth but the problem is that when the page is refreshed, you can see the menu show up for a split second before it transitions under the header. This can also be seen when you're manually resizing the viewport from a width larger than `768px` and when it gets to `767px`, you can the see the menu appear for a split second before it disappears. Please I need help to make this behaviour stop. Below is the code required to recreate this problem:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: fit-content;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 65px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#header-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

/* Navigation */

nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Hamburger menu button */

.menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -42px;
  left: -25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 24px 14px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navicon {
  background-color: #222222;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 26px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

.navicon:before,
.navicon:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #222222;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

.navicon:before {
  top: 9px;
}

.navicon:after {
  bottom: 9px;
}

/* Hamburger Menu Animation Start */

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0;
}

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  bottom: 0;
}

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* Hide blue background on hamburger menu tap on some mobile devices */

.menu-icon,
.menu-btn,
.navicon {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

/* Nav items */

.menu {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 65px;
  padding: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.3192s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}


.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 0.3192s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li {
  border-top: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  padding: 10px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu a {
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu a,
.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu li {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .logo {
    width: 60vw;
    margin-top: 0;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }

  nav {
    width: 40vw;
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    transform: none;
    transition: none;
    position: static;
    margin: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .menu li {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: none;
  }

  .menu a {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Product Landing Page</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <main id="main">
      <header id="header">

        <div class="logo">
          <img id="header-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/original_trombones.png" alt="original trombones logo">
        </div>

        <input type="checkbox" class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
        <label for="menu-btn" class="menu-icon"><span class="navicon"></span></label>

        <nav id="nav-bar">
          <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#features" class="nav-link">Feautures</a></li>
            <li><a href="#how-it-works" class="nav-link">How it Works</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pricing" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>

      </header>
    </main>
  </body>

</html>
```

I also provided a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ph8Lf1xw/) you can use to check out the problem.

*P.S: The original codepen I got the idea from also has the same issue if you copy the code and preview it in a browser and reload the page.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using javascript we can add the `stop-transition` class to the body for some few milliseconds. Then in the css we can add the rule to stop play any transition momentarily. After that, when the resize is done, we can remove the `stop-transition` class from the body to make sure that everything acts accordingly.

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9otp2wd3/).

```js
(function () {
  const classes = document.body.classList;
  let timer = null;
  window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    if (timer){
      clearTimeout(timer);
      timer = null;
    } else {
      classes.add('stop-transition');
    }
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      classes.remove('stop-transition');
      timer = null;
    }, 100);
  });
})();
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: fit-content;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

/* Stop playing transition momentarily on viewport resize. */
body.stop-transition .menu {
  transition: none;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 65px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#header-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

/* Navigation */

nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Hamburger menu button */

.menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -42px;
  left: -25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 24px 14px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navicon {
  background-color: #222222;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 26px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

.navicon:before,
.navicon:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #222222;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

.navicon:before {
  top: 9px;
}

.navicon:after {
  bottom: 9px;
}

/* Hamburger Menu Animation Start */

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0;
}

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  bottom: 0;
}

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* Hide blue background on hamburger menu tap on some mobile devices */

.menu-icon,
.menu-btn,
.navicon {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

/* Nav items */

.menu {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 65px;
  padding: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.3192s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}


.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 0.3192s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li {
  border-top: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  padding: 10px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu a {
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu a,
.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu li {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .logo {
    width: 60vw;
    margin-top: 0;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }

  nav {
    width: 40vw;
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    transform: none;
    transition: none;
    position: static;
    margin: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .menu li {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: none;
  }

  .menu a {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<main id="main">
   <header id="header">

     <div class="logo">
       <img id="header-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/original_trombones.png" alt="original trombones logo">
     </div>

     <input type="checkbox" class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
     <label for="menu-btn" class="menu-icon"><span class="navicon"></span></label>

     <nav id="nav-bar">
       <ul class="menu">
         <li><a href="#features" class="nav-link">Feautures</a></li>
         <li><a href="#how-it-works" class="nav-link">How it Works</a></li>
         <li><a href="#pricing" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
       </ul>
     </nav>

   </header>
 </main>
```