# Click checked pure hamburger menu on window/document click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

This question may seem similar to other questions but my hamburger menu uses checkbox to function and shows up at `768px` width and below and I've been running into issues trying to close the open hamburger menu when the window/document is clicked.
I successfully got it to work using several ways but it still doesn't work as intended. The hamburger menu closes on document click alright, but the hamburger menu no longer closes on hamburger menu click as it originally should.
I have very little knowledge of Javascript/Jquery but I understand the bits I used to make other parts of the code work, but I just can't figure out how to make this particular one work.
Below is the code required to recreate the problem:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Script to push the section down on menu click

  $(".menu-btn").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".main-content").toggleClass("open");
  });

  // Script to collapse menu on link click

  $(".nav-link").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".menu-btn").click();
  });

  //Script to close the menu on window/document click

  //With Jquery

  $(document).click(function(e) {
    if (!$('.menu-btn').is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the button...
      &&
      ($(('.menu-btn')).is(":checked"))) {
      $('.menu-btn').click();
    }
  });
});

//With vanilla JS

/* window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (document.getElementById('menu-btn').checked) {
    document.getElementById('menu-btn').click();
  }
} */
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  min-width: fit-content;
}

body {
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
}

header {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 65px;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.logo {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

#header-img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
}

/* Navigation */

nav {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Hamburger menu button */

.menu-btn {
  display: none;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -42px;
  left: -25px;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 24px 14px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.navicon {
  background-color: #222222;
  display: block;
  height: 3px;
  width: 26px;
  position: relative;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

.navicon:before,
.navicon:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #222222;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

.navicon:before {
  top: 9px;
}

.navicon:after {
  bottom: 9px;
}

/* Hamburger Menu Animation Start */

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  top: 0;
}

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  bottom: 0;
}

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
  background: transparent;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* Hide blue background on hamburger menu tap on some mobile devices */

.menu-icon,
.menu-btn,
.navicon {
  -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

/* Nav items */

.menu {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  list-style-type: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-top: 65px;
  padding: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: visibility 0.3192s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}


.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: visibility 0.3192s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li {
  border-top: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  padding: 10px 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu a {
  color: #222222;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu a,
.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu li {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* MAIN CONTENT  */

.main-content {
  margin-top: 100px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  margin-right: 30px;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* For jquery */

.main-content.open {
  margin-top: 195px;
  transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* First section */

section.hero {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}

h2 {
  margin: 0;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#form input[type="email"] {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 6px;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

#form input[type="submit"] {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 150px;
  height: 30px;
  margin: 15px 0;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f1c40f;
  font-family: inherit;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}


/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
  }

  .logo {
    width: 60vw;
    margin-top: 0;
    justify-content: flex-start;
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: none;
  }

  nav {
    width: 40vw;
    margin-top: 0;
  }

  .menu {
    width: 100%;
    transform: none;
    transition: none;
    position: static;
    margin: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
  }

  .menu li {
    border: none;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: none;
  }

  .menu a {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main id="main">
  <header id="header">

    <div class="logo">
      <img id="header-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/original_trombones.png" alt="original trombones logo">
    </div>

    <input type="checkbox" class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
    <label for="menu-btn" class="menu-icon"><span class="navicon"></span></label>

    <nav id="nav-bar">

      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#features" class="nav-link">Feautures</a></li>
        <li><a href="#how-it-works" class="nav-link">How it Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#pricing" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
      </ul>

    </nav>

  </header>

  <div class="main-content">

    <section class="hero">
      <h2>Handcrafted, home-made masterpieces</h2>
      <form action="" id="form">
        <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
        <input type="submit" value="GET STARTED" id="submit">
      </form>
    </section>

  </div>
</main>
```

Here is also a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zopsewL1/) of the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pure CSS Hamburger menu shows up when resizing viewport before disappearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63861504/pure-css-hamburger-menu-shows-up-when-resizing-viewport-before-disappearing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is in this line:

```
$('.menu-btn').click();
```

It's enough you changed it to this:

```
e.preventDefault();
$('.menu-btn').click();
```

With the first line you prevent the default action while with the second you initiated the click event for the correct element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Script to push the section down on menu click

    $(".menu-btn").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".main-content").toggleClass("open");
    });

    // Script to collapse menu on link click

    $(".nav-link").click(function(e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(".menu-btn").click();
    });

    //Script to close the menu on window/document click

    //With Jquery

    $(document).click(function(e) {
        if (!$('.menu-btn').is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the button...
                &&
                ($(('.menu-btn')).is(":checked"))) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('.menu-btn').click();
        }
    });
});
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    min-width: fit-content;
}

body {
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    padding: 0 20px;
    height: 65px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
}

.logo {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

#header-img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
}

/* Navigation */

nav {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Hamburger menu button */

.menu-btn {
    display: none;
}

.menu-icon {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    top: -42px;
    left: -25px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 24px 14px;
    z-index: 1;
}

.navicon {
    background-color: #222222;
    display: block;
    height: 3px;
    width: 26px;
    position: relative;
    transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

.navicon:before,
.navicon:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #222222;
    transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

.navicon:before {
    top: 9px;
}

.navicon:after {
    bottom: 9px;
}

/* Hamburger Menu Animation Start */

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:before {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    top: 0;
}

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon:after {
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    bottom: 0;
}

.menu-btn:checked~.menu-icon .navicon {
    background: transparent;
    transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* Hide blue background on hamburger menu tap on some mobile devices */

.menu-icon,
.menu-btn,
.navicon {
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
}

/* Nav items */

.menu {
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    list-style-type: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin-top: 65px;
    padding: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: visibility 0.3192s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}


.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: visibility 0.3192s ease-in-out, opacity 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

.menu li {
    border-top: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
    padding: 10px 0;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu a {
    color: #222222;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu a,
.menu-btn:checked~nav .menu li {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* MAIN CONTENT  */

.main-content {
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* For jquery */

.main-content.open {
    margin-top: 195px;
    transition: 0.3192s ease-in-out;
}

/* First section */

section.hero {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    margin: 0;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
}

#form input[type="email"] {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 300px;
    padding: 6px;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 0.9rem;
    border: 1px solid #c7c7c7;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

#form input[type="submit"] {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 150px;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 15px 0;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #f1c40f;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 500;
}


/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    header {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: space-around;
    }

    .logo {
        width: 60vw;
        margin-top: 0;
        justify-content: flex-start;
    }

    .menu-icon {
        display: none;
    }

    nav {
        width: 40vw;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .menu {
        width: 100%;
        transform: none;
        transition: none;
        position: static;
        margin: 0;
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .menu li {
        border: none;
        padding: 0;
        opacity: 1;
        transition: none;
    }

    .menu a {
        opacity: 1;
        transition: none;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main id="main">
    <header id="header">

        <div class="logo">
            <img id="header-img" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/freecodecamp/original_trombones.png" alt="original trombones logo">
        </div>

        <input type="checkbox" class="menu-btn" id="menu-btn">
        <label for="menu-btn" class="menu-icon"><span class="navicon"></span></label>

        <nav id="nav-bar">

            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="#features" class="nav-link">Feautures</a></li>
                <li><a href="#how-it-works" class="nav-link">How it Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#pricing" class="nav-link">Pricing</a></li>
            </ul>

        </nav>

    </header>

    <div class="main-content">

        <section class="hero">
            <h2>Handcrafted, home-made masterpieces</h2>
            <form action="" id="form">
                <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email address" required>
                <input type="submit" value="GET STARTED" id="submit">
            </form>
        </section>

    </div>
</main>
```